# Obtain Time format from a String

Tags: r

I am getting Data where the first column is always a string with the Time like

```
Time <- "2015-06-01 09:45:33"
```

for plotting, later I convert it with as.POSIXct and so on.

But sometimes I have another Time string like

```
Time <- "2015/07/01 09:33"
```

So is there a possibility(or a function) to check the Time format of the string in a way like this

```
format <- checkFormat(Time)
```

and then convert it automatically to

`as.POSIXct(Time, format=format)`

I cant be the first one who asks this, although i really searched a lot.

Thanks

Comment: My guess is no, since for example in your example, you can not be certain wether 06 is the month and 01 is the date or vice versa.

Comment: If you are happy with a non-`base` solution, see `lubridate::parse_date_time` and use the `orders` argument to specify relevant date time formats in your data: `parse_date_time(x = c("2015-06-01 09:45:33", "2015/07/01 09:33"), orders = c("Y m d H M S", "Y m d H M"))`.

Comment: @Wannes Rosiers:  I also had this in mind. But nice to know that there is no way to do it . How can I put your comment as an answer?

Comment: @Henrik Thanks, I will try to figure this out as soon as i have the time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested in answer format: it is not possible, since in your example no solution can know if 06 is the month and 01 the day or vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the time format string with

```
Time <- "2015/07/01 09:33"
Time <- if(grepl("\\d{4}/\\d{2}/\\d{2}", Time)) gsub("/", "-", Time)
```

Comment: I am sorry, this was not really the question, because the Time Format as I said can always change this was just an example